# Rails query to get highest amount

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this function:

```
     Order.find_by_amount().amount
```

I am stuck at what to insert in () to get highest amount.

Comment: you want highest amount or last amount added

Answer (score 1):

To get highest amount you can use aggregate functions:

eg: `Order.maximum(:amount)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `find_by` methods.
You can do this with:

```
Order.order(:amount).last.amount #the second order is to sort in your database
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If `amount` is a field in `orders` table then you can get the highest amount order by this

```
Order.order('amount DESC').first.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be any problem if you google it first. Please do search first.

Here 3 possible ways to do it

```
# default sorting order is ascending order 
Order.order(:amount).last.amount

# order the amount in descending order
Order.order('amount DESC').first.amount

# Calculates the maximum value on a given column. 
Order.maximum(:amount)
```